# Firebase Auth Signout not pushing to homepage in React web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a 'sign out' button which obviously deletes the user session when submitted.

The token gets removed when the button is clicked, and I'm then wanting it to redirect to the homepage once the token is successfully removed. However, it pulls up the following error when the button is clicked:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props')

I don't understand why this would be the case, as the code in principle is similar to other functions which call 'this.props.history.push'.

Here's my component:

```
class ProfileBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

  }

  async signOut(e) {

    e.preventDefault()

    await firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      console.log("Successfully signed out.")

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
      console.log("An error occurred")
    });

    this.props.history.push("/");
  }

  render() {
    return (

          <button className="profile-box-logout" type="submit" name="button" onClick={this.signOut}>Logout</button>

    )
  }

}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue doesn't have anything to do with Firebase. `this` is null inside that function, and that is throwing the error. If you move the function inside the render, then it will work. Try something like this:

```js
render() {

    const signOut = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      await firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        console.log("Successfully signed out.")

      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
        console.log("An error occurred")
      });

      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
    
    return (
      <button
        className="profile-box-logout"
        type="submit"
        name="button"
        onClick={signOut}
      >
        Logout
      </button>
    );
  }
```

That will give you access to `this.props`. Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-forked-sbrnd?file=/components/Schedule.js

Comment: Unfortunately that's not worked. I'm getting this error: 
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.history.push')

Comment: I have a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-forked-sbrnd?file=/components/Schedule.js Take a look and see if anything else looks different.

Comment: How strange.. I've tried it on your Sandbox and it's working so you're right. It's not for me though.. I've tried taking the Firebase code out, that didn't impact. The code's exactly the same but it's not working for me.

Comment: I've got it.. I needed to wrap the component in 'withRouter', as it was being passed to a parent component. Thanks for your help!